# How to get text from div[html+jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm changing code of an animation for my purposes and can't get text from the div to animate it.

Original animation:
https://codepen.io/Lunoware/pen/gjYjBw

My code(I deleted input, inupt parts of script and "if" instruction)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p id="text">Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@background: #0bc020;


  #text{
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition-duration: 1.5s;
    .char-outer-space{
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    .char-outer{
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 5px;
      .char-inner{
        position: absolute;
        animation-name: jumping;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        left:0px;
        top:-15px;
      } 
    }
  }
}

@keyframes jumping {
    from {
      transform: translate(0, 8px);
    }
    to {
      transform: translate(0, -0px);
    }
}
```

jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      function splitHtmlString(text){

        var string = '#text';  

        var charArr = string.split("");
        var fixedString = "";
        charArr.forEach(function(char, index) {

          var offset = -index/10;

          if(char != " "){
            fixedString += "<span class='char-outer' style='animation-delay:" + offset + "s;'><span class='char-inner' style='animation-delay:" + offset + "s;'>" + char + "</span></span>";
          }else{
            fixedString += "<span class='char-outer-space'></span>";
          }
        });

        $("#text").html(fixedString);
      }
      splitHtmlString("");
    });
```

I need the line that will get the text from the  div

Comment: Just use `$('#text').html()` or `$('#text').text()` to get your text.

Comment: Working! Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&channel=crow&q=jquery+get+text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more reference in [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

```
//get value as html
$('#text').html()
//get value as text  
$('#text').text()
```

Comment: His problem was, his having a hard time getting the tag's value, so I suggested using the following code.

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer. You can edit it anytime!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('text').innerText,
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML
```